# Не работает callback_query_handler() в Python Telebot

Tags: python, telebot, inline

Всем привет! Создаю двух-язычного (ru, en) тг бота. *Ниже часть кода с проблемой*:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['lang'])
def start_func(message):   
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    rus = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Русский ', callback_data='rus')
    eng = types.InlineKeyboardButton('English ', callback_data='eng')
    markup.row(rus, eng)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Please, choose the language you want to continue in below again ', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def language(callback):
    if callback.data == 'rus':
        markup1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Продолжить', callback_data='да')
        markup1.add(btn1)
        bot.edit_message_text(f'Привет, {callback.from_user.first_name}! Вы выбрали <b>Русский</b>  язык. <b>Продолжить?</b> \n\nIf you want to change your choice, write /lang', callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup1)
        
    elif callback.data == 'eng':
        markup2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Continue', callback_data='yes')
        markup2.add(btn2)
        bot.edit_message_text(f'Hello, {callback.from_user.first_name}! You chose <b>English</b>  language. <b>Continue?</b> \n\nЕсли вы хотите изменить свой выбор, напишите /lang', callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup2)
    

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def choose_mood(message):
    print(message)
    text = f'Ещё раз привет, {message.from_user.first_name}, я - бот <b>Cool Pictures</b>! \n\nЯ помогу Вам найти интересные картинки по вашему вкусу. Для начала выберите настроение картинки из плиток в низу экрана.'
    if message.data == 'да':
        text = text
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2,resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1r = types.KeyboardButton('Весёлое ')
        btn2r = types.KeyboardButton('Нейтральное ')
        btn3r = types.KeyboardButton('Грустное ')
        markup.add(btn1r)
        markup.add(btn2r)
        markup.add(btn3r)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)

    elif message.data == 'yes':
        text = translator.translate(text, crs='ru', dest='en').text        
        markup1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2,resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1e = types.KeyboardButton('Happy ')
        btn2e = types.KeyboardButton('Neutral ')
        btn3e = types.KeyboardButton('Sad ')
        markup1.add(btn1e)
        markup1.add(btn2e)
        markup1.add(btn3e)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup1)
```

Дело в том, что Inline кнопка "Продолжить" появляется, но после её нажатия ничего не происходит, то есть не срабатывает функция "choose_mood". **Что я делаю не так?** Если понадобится полный код - пишите, я отредактирую! Всем заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что каждый обработчик для бота должен быть в одном экземпляре (а в коде выше функции с `@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)` объявлены сразу две), иначе обработчики, которые были объявлены после самого первого, будут игнорироваться (в коде функция `choose_mood` игнорируется, так как уже есть `language`).

Вам надо объединить функции `language` и `choose_mood` в одну:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def language(callback):
    text = f'Ещё раз привет, {callback.from_user.first_name}, я - бот <b>Cool Pictures</b>! \n\nЯ помогу Вам найти интересные картинки по вашему вкусу. Для начала выберите настроение картинки из плиток в низу экрана.'
    if callback.data == 'rus':
        markup1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Продолжить', callback_data='да')
        markup1.add(btn1)
        bot.edit_message_text(f'Привет, {callback.from_user.first_name}! Вы выбрали <b>Русский</b>  язык. <b>Продолжить?</b> \n\nIf you want to change your choice, write /lang', callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup1)

    elif callback.data == 'eng':
        markup2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Continue', callback_data='yes')
        markup2.add(btn2)
        bot.edit_message_text(f'Hello, {callback.from_user.first_name}! You chose <b>English</b>  language. <b>Continue?</b> \n\nЕсли вы хотите изменить свой выбор, напишите /lang', callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup2)

    if callback.data == 'да':
        text = text
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2, resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1r = types.KeyboardButton('Весёлое ')
        btn2r = types.KeyboardButton('Нейтральное ')
        btn3r = types.KeyboardButton('Грустное ')
        markup.add(btn1r)
        markup.add(btn2r)
        markup.add(btn3r)
        bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, text, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)

    elif callback.data == 'yes':
        text = translator.translate(text, crs='ru', dest='en').text
        markup1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2, resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1e = types.KeyboardButton('Happy ')
        btn2e = types.KeyboardButton('Neutral ')
        btn3e = types.KeyboardButton('Sad ')
        markup1.add(btn1e)
        markup1.add(btn2e)
        markup1.add(btn3e)
        bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, text, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup1)
```

В обработчиках вы всё ещё можете писать разные условия:

```
# Если данные с нажатия кнопки равны "X"
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: callback.data == "X")
def func_x(callback):
    ...

# Если они равны "Y"
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: callback.data == "Y")
def func_y(callback):
    ...
```

Comment: Вставлять ответы на вопросы, даже не зная, могут ли они помочь именно с этой проблемой, это как минимум глупо

Comment: @Cheburkek В моём профиле есть ссылка на Discord, напиши мне туда, чтобы комментарии не засорять